# ANN_MLP missing attribute in python OpenCV3

Tags: python, opencv, neural-network, opencv3.1

I'm trying to run some sample OpenCV3 Neural Network code in Python.

```
import cv2
model = cv2.ml.ANN_MLP()
model.load('mlp.xml')
```

But this gives me the error:

```
module 'cv2.ml' has no attribute 'ANN_MLP'
```

But, there is such a class in OpenCV3 release notes http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d0/dce/classcv_1_1ml_1_1ANN__MLP.html
and the code above did work on somebody's system since it is given as sample code.

I'm using Anaconda on Windows 10, with python 3.5.3 and opencv3 3.1.0.

What is going on?

1. Is there something obvious I'm missing here?
2. Does the python version of OpenCV3 not have the wrapper?
3. Did OpenCV3 python have a wrapper once upon a time and was removed in the newer versions?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error beause the python version of OpenCV (i.e.) 3.1 is missing the load wrapper. You can confirm this by checking the following in the python REPL - dir(cv2.ml)

This has been resolved in ver 3.2.0+

In order to create a model by loading the ANN_MLP weights you need to do the following -

model = cv2.ml.ANN_MLP_load(filename)

Comment: Apologies for that. I have updated my answer with the actual solution.